# How This Code Loops Without Any Loop Statement or 'goto' or Recursion?

Tags: c++, c, loops, undefined-behavior

The following code does not contain any loop, or `goto`, or recursion; yet it prints from 1 to 10 in the console.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int n = 1;

void foo() {
    int x;

    printf("%d ", n);
    if (++n>10) return;

    *(&x+4) -= 5;
}

int main() {
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

This mysterious code `*(&x+4) -= 5;` is causing the loop.

---

As much as I have understood- the value of `x` is being kept in stack memory. So may be, before that `(&x+4)` there is the pointer of the function `foo`, and `foo` is being recursively called.

Then again, I am not sure if my assumptions are right. I also do not understand where that `5` comes from. I tried to print and analyze the addresses (advised by my colleague) of the function pointer and variables; and match them with my knowledge of [C memory layout](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/). But I got more confused.

---

If there were more variables declared before and after `x`, how `*(&x+4) -= 5;` would change?

---

**OS:** Windows-7 64 bit, **Compiler:** GNU GCC, **Editor:** CodeBlocks 16.01

Comment: It only prints `1` and then exits.

Comment: This depends on undefined behaviour. You are not suppose to dereference a memory at `(&x+4)` when `x` is just `int x`.

Comment: @Deanie I have used gcc compiler. Prints 1 to 10 both in C and C++.

Comment: @TheDeepThinker I have used gcc compiler.  Prints 1 with a space and then exits.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I found the code online. I know- I should not code like that. I simply want to know the **explanation**.

Comment: Self-modifying code relying on stack layout and HW architecture details. This question is useless without those details provided. F.ex. on my Fedora 29 x86_64 with gcc 8.2.1 I only get a segmentation fault. No bug surprise there, to be honest...

Comment: @StefanBecker It's not "self-modifying code", it's just corrupting its own stack.

Comment: @duskwuff Thanks for you comment. Could you please tell how the stack is being corrupted.

Comment: @duskwuff in my book modifying the return address on the stack is self-modifying code.

Comment: @StefanBecker In my book, it's only "self-modifying code" if it's _modifying code_. The stack is data, not code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior of `*(&x+4) -= 5;` is undefined because it writes outside the bounds of any object allocated by the program. What this does will depend on what happens to be stored at that address, if anything. So the short answer to why your code behaves so strangely is that the code has a bug that results in its behavior being unpredictable.

What is probably happening on your platform is that it likely winds up modifying the address that it returns to, causing it to return to `main` before the call to `foo`, resulting in `main` calling `foo` again.

Comment: Just because the code isn't valid C or C++ doesn't necessarily mean it's buggy. If it came with instructions that it is intended to be compiled with a specific version of GCC for Windows 7, then it depends on the behavior of the compiler. It might not even be undocumented behavior.

Comment: I've never seen any compiler document something like that. If it relies on undocumented behavior, it's buggy. There's no way to know under what conditions the behavior will occur or not occur.

Answer (score 2):

David is right. When a code is trying to write or even access something in the memory block that is not allocated to it, it can do anything (even a nuclear explosion if there is, let's say, some function's address that does shit with reactor). It's your responsibility to take care of memory allocations as C is not a strongly-typed language. It's just a co-incidence that its causing a loop. On my system, it works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying the stack in `*(&x+4) -= 5;` That is undefined behaviour, and under undefined behaviour anything is allowed to happen, even to make demons fly out of your nose. See http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html

Maybe for a specific HW with a specific compiler you get always the same behaviour, but it does not need to.